# Where to put JS "build output"

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, babeljs

I have a NodeJS project that has some server and client side, both written in ES2015 and compiled to ES5 with Babel, executed by Gulp.

Coming from the Java land, I made the build process put the results in a dist folder, so the directory structure looks like this:

```
./node_modules
./client
./server
./static
./dist/client # Result of /client compilation
./dist/server # Result of /server compilation
```

Now this is somewhat ugly, because some things land in a different place, on a different depth. You run into all kinds of problems. Carefully count the dots in imports. Use `__dirname` vs. `process.cwd()` to get things relative to the right "root". Run the app with ugly-ish path like `node dist/server/server.js`. And so on.

How do you typically solve this problem? Would you put compilation results on the same level, in different directory names:

```
./build-client
./build-server
```

Something else?

Answer (score 0):

> You run into all kinds of problems

Could you enumerate these specifically? I personally don't find this structure problematic.

> __dirname

There is no need to use `__dirname` for imports. If you do an import with a relative path, `__dirname` is implied. Using the relative path is the idiomatic thing. It's also better as `__dirname` will be absolute and thus system-specific and thus have deployment/sharing problems.

Although you technically can use this for CommonJS modules, and babel may even support it, ES2015 requires imports to be static strings, so when node eventually supports ES2015 modules natively, anything that isn't a static string will likely be unsupported.

> process.cwd()

This cannot be used as it would cause you program to fail most of the time anyone other than you was trying to run it and didn't happen to be in the correct directory. Also this will not work in ES2015.

---

Overall, my suggestion is

A. If your client and server code are mostly separate, and the relative paths are mostly just `./` and `../` within the directories, it's fine, just adjust to be comfortable with it.

B. If you are commonly importing in between client and server, the code is coupled, and you might reconsider whether client/server is the right axis on which to separate your code. If your app is highly "isomorphic", just restructure you code to reflect the actual coupling that exists across the code and you will naturally minimize the depth of `../../` paths necessary.

> My main pain point is really having the output nested in "dist" directory, I wonder how that is usually addressed

You don't need to address this in the source code. Your client side bundler (webpack, browserify, or similar), will use handle third party dependencies from npm automatically using the node require algorithm. If you have a non-npm vendored dependency, just reference that with a relative path and your bundler will handle it.

If you want further help, I suggest you reformat your question from generic to very very specific with the paths and tools and details specified so we can comment directly on your situation instead of something hypothetical/generic.

Comment: I don't have any imports from client to server or vice versa. But if I had a non-compiled "vendor" directory in project root, how would I import that?

__dirname vs. process.cwd() - not used for imports, but useful for reading static files, configs etc.

My main pain point is really having the output nested in "dist" directory, I wonder how that is usually addressed.